# prepending relative links to absolute links in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, prepend

I am trying to turn all relative links in a list into absolute urls.  My list has currently includes both relative and absolute values.  I want my code to correct the relative links and ignore all of the absolute values.  My first attempt was as follows:

```
for link in list:
   if link.startswith('/'):
       link.prepend('https://acme.com')
```

I receive errors in relation to link and prepend.

I then researched and found an option using list comprehension and tried this:

```
for link in list:
   if link.startswith('/'):
      ['https://www.acme.com{0}'.format(link) for link in list]
```

This partially worked, but it ignored my if statement and added to every link in my list.

Comment: `link_list = ['https://www.acme.com{0}'.format(link) if link.startswith('/') else link for link in link_list]`

Comment: First `list` is a builtin class name; please don't name your variables `list` or any other builtin that could be shadowed. Next, `['https://www.acme.com{0}'.format(link) if link.startswith('/') else link for link in url_list]`; where `url_list` is your list of links.